# iOS 5.0 didSelectAnnotationView

Tags: ios, ios5, mapkit

Bit of a frustration trying to get a didSelectAnnotationView to get called....

My situation:
Using a TabBar Controller, my app switches from INDEX view to a MAP view (INDEX tab to MAP tab) when one of the items in the index is selected. No problem getting this to work under 4.3, but an interesting problem under 5.0.

If I have had previously selected the MAP tab (as in the MAP view has loaded), the annotation "bubble" pops up to show the selected point...no problem. But, if I had not selected the MAP tab previous to selecting one of items from the index list, it loads the MAP view, but does not call the didSelectAnnotationView method.

This only happens once...as in, once the MAP view has been loaded, everything responds as expected.

And again, under 4.3 the didSelectAnnotationView is called every time, regardless of whether the MAP view has been loaded previously or not.

Any thoughts...?

As for my coding, I load all of the annotations under the viewDidLoad method and the viewWillAppear is as such:

```
//Run through all annotations
for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in mapView.annotations) {

    //Check if that annotation is the selected one
    if (annotation.coordinate.longitude == mylongitude) {
        [[mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation] setHidden:FALSE];
        [mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you got the solution? I am facing the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

(my rep isn't high enough to post a comment yet)

1. First, verify that your annotation is being found in your problem scenario -- put a breakpoint in your IF statement to confirm.

Other notes:

- If the annotation you're trying to select is off-screen, the select method won't have any effect (per the documentation).  The annotation will certainly be available, but it probably won't have a view associated with it in this case.
- Make sure the annotation isn't already selected when you call select... maybe try de-selecting all annotations before you go into your loop.
- Not sure why you're calling 'setHidden' on the annotation view, but I'd remove any bits that try to hide or show the annotation views.  For the most part, this is up to the MKMapView to deal with the details of the annotation views themselves (in terms of displaying them, positioning them, etc.)